# what is wrong with this select query

Tags: sql, vb.net

This is my sql server select query in vb.net.

```
Try
    retrieveRecord("ProductBasicInfo", "ProdID = " & txtProdID.Text.Trim)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dsSql.Tables("ProductBasicInfo")
    MessageBox.Show("ok")
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

and this is the function which receives the query:

```
Public Sub retrieveRecord(ByVal tblname As String, ByVal parameter As String)

    Try
        If dsSql.Tables.Contains(tblname) Then
            dsSql.Tables.Remove(tblname)
        End If

        cmdSql1.CommandText = "select * from " & tblname & "where " & parameter & ""
        cmdSql1.Connection = Connect()
        daSql.SelectCommand = cmdSql1
        daSql.Fill(dsSql, tblname)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try


End Sub
```

It gives error that incorrect syntax near =? Please guide me that where i am doing mistake.

Comment: You're missing a space between `tblname` and `where`.

Answer (score 3):

In generating your SQL statement

```
cmdSql1.CommandText = "select * from " & tblname & "where " & parameter & ""
```

You are neglecting to insert a space between the table name and your WHERE clause....

```
cmdSql1.CommandText = "select * from " & tblname & " where " & parameter & ""
```

...also, the ending  **& ""** is moot, extraneous.

Comment: Ohhh, i was unknown about it. Thank you EkE, MPelletier for your devoted guidance.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a space between tblname and where and you probably want quotes around txtProdID.Text.Trim.

Comment: Those quotes are technically unneeded if the value is numeric

Comment: but if that field is varchar it will return nothing